# What are these schüchternen Liebespaare doing?

Tags: german-to-english

The below sentence comes from an article "[Tanger ist Europa](http://www.zeit.de/2016/31/marokko-sicheres-herkunftsland-tanger)" in *ZEIT ONLINE*. It describes what some of the guests in café Hafa in Tangier, Morocco, are doing. It evades me what the "shy love couples" are doing.

> Schweigsame Männer bröseln Kif in Holzpfeifen, **schüchterne Liebespaare vergessen in der Musikblase ihrer vor sich hin dudelnden Handys die Welt**.

Comment: Was ist Dir daran unklar? Die Grammatik? Vokabeln? Der Satzbau?

Comment: @user unknown At the time of reading the sentence, the situation described seemed to me so weird that I thought I didn't understand the meaning of the part highlighted in bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be translated (very) roughly to: They forget the world, inside the music bubble, which's blaring/humming from their mobile phone in front of them.

It's easier to understand, if I rewrite it as following: "schüchterne Liebespaare vergessen die Welt, in der Musikblase ihrer vor sich hin dudelnden Handys."

Comment: Really weird: couples sitting at tables in a café and each listening to the music coming from their mobile phones. But that seems to be what the sentence is saying.

Comment: Couple do the couple thing (cuddle & listening to music), when they don't have anything to say to each other, I guess.

Comment: To me, _blaring_ indicates a certain loudness, which is not part of _dudeln_. _Dudeln_ is done by flowing, unobstrusive, non-distracting background music. In contrast, _blaring_ music demands attention.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Headphones?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s do this step by step. First, identify the verb.

> [S]chüchterne Liebespaare **vergessen** in der Musikblase ihrer vor sich hin dudelnden Handys die Welt.

(*dudelnden* is a form derived from a verb, but it is a participle so it now functions adverbially or adjectivally.) Since our verb is *vergessen*, we now have to look for a possible subject and an object (*jemand{nom} vergisst etwas{akk}*). (There are no infinitives, so thankfully a whole bunch of problems simply does not exist.)

> **[S]chüchterne Liebespaare** vergessen *in der Musikblase* ihrer vor sich hin dudelnden Handys **die Welt.**

You have already identified *schüchterne Liebespaare* as the sentence’s subject, which is correct. The object can only be a different noun. We get *in der Musikblase*, *something … Handys*, *sich* (I’ll come back to those two) and *die Welt.* It cannot be *in der Musikblase*, since we are not looking for a prepositional object but an accusative one. (Also, *Musikblase* is dative here.) So *die Welt* is a very strong contestant.

What about *sich*? Well, if it’s sich, it would likely be *vor sich* which doesn’t really make sense, and it would leave the fragment *hin dudelnden Handys* which doesn’t make sense either.

What about the *Handys*? It’s difficult, but you have to follow up on everything that modifies them. First up, the adjectival *dudelnden*. This gives us a strong hint on *Handys*’ genus (the number is inferred by the plural-s): Unless we find an article-like modifier (definite article or possessive pronoun) it has to be dative plural. Well, looking around, we find an *ihrer* before *Handys* which very likely attaches to them (there is no other noun in between, there is no corresponding preposition and the verb does not take genitive nowadays). Assuming that *ihrer* and *Handys* go together, so would *vor sich hin dudelnden* which works (we’ll se how in a second).

Having identified subject and object, we can reduce the sentence to its bare minimum:

> [Schüchterne Liebespaare vergessen die Welt.

So shy couples forget about the world around them.

Everything else just adds further precision to this core sentence. *Where* are they forgetting about the world? *In der Musikblase* (In the bubble of music). In *whose* music bubble? *In der Musikblase **ihrer Handys*** (in the music bubble of their mobiles). *What* kind of a mobile? *Ihrer **vor sich hin dudelnden** Handys.*

Okay, that last one may still warrant a short note. The full verbal expression is *vor sich hin dudeln*, so a sentence could be ‘das Handy dudelt vor sich hin.’ The meaning is to just to jingle/sing/make music to yourself. So *ihre vor sich hin dudelnden Handys* are their mobiles which seem to just be quietly playing music to themselves.